# What kind of blocks do create closure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

After working so long with Javascript, I'm still having problems coming to terms with closure!

```js
(function() {
    var pages = ["one", "two", "three"];
    for (var index in pages) {
        var p = pages[index];
        setTimeout(function() { console.log(p); }, 500);
    }
})();
```

Shouldn't the above snippet print `one`, `two` and `three`? AFAIK `p` is within the closure created by `for` block and should remain unchanged for the each of `setTimeout`s to pick them up! So why is it printing three `three`s?

Comment: This might help: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/#closures, http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-6-closures/

Comment: "the closure created by `for` block" in JavaScript, blocks do not create closures. Only functions do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has *function scope*, not *block scope*.  So, when you are looping over your array (P.S. *don't* use `for..in` for arrays), you are creating 3 closures.  Each closure you create is referencing the *same* `p` variable.  So when then timeouts eventually run, they will *all* print `"three"` because they are all printing the *same* `p` variable.

You need to create a new scope for each element in the array.  Lucky, JavaScript has a built-in function just for this, [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
(function() {
 var pages = ["one", "two", "three"];
 pages.forEach(function(p){
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(p); }, 500);
 });
})();
```

When this runs, it runs the callback for each element.  When that callback is ran, a new scope is created for each element, thus it works properly.

Comment: Its a good idea to prefix the first line with a semicolon (;) if you are dealing with code that is not strictly linted to have trailing semi-colons. Otherwise, JavaScript interpreter will greedily assume that the block is associated with the last code block interpreted. Eg: `;(function (){ ...` .

Answer (score 4):

`for` blocks don't create closures. In JavaScript only function creates scope and is a closure. So you could write your code like this:

```
(function() {
    var pages = ["one", "two", "three"];
    for (var index in pages) {
        var p = pages[index];
        (function (p) {
          setTimeout(function() { console.log(p); }, 500);
        }(p));
    }
})();
```

Comment: You seem to confuse closures with scope.

Comment: @FelixKling I was trying to clarify when OP states that `AFAIK p is within the closure created by for block`.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense now. The statement *functions create closures* still sounds weird to me. I'd say a function creates *scope* and *is* a closure. But maybe that's just me :)

Comment: @FelixKling I accept this suggestion and have introduced the function scope in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the delay, the "p" is being reset by the time it goes to read it. Send the "p" to a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/RCzech/pkk4pe3q/

```
(function() {
var pages = ["one", "two", "three"];
for (var index in pages) {
    var p = pages[index];
    timeout(p);
}
})();

function timeout (p){
setTimeout(function() { console.log(p); }, 500)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue because of `setTimeout` function, so needs implement function which return function it names as closure of function logger in this case

```
(function () {
    var pages = ["one", "two", "three"];
    for (var index in pages) {
        var p = pages[index];
        setTimeout(logger(p), 500);
    }


})();

function logger(p) {
    return function () {
        console.log(p)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? They clearly seem to not understand how closures work in JS, so just posting some code is not helpful.

Comment: fixed answer for this question